# Using results from grep to write results line by line with sed

Tags: sed, grep

I am trying to take every file name in a directory that has the extension .text
and write it to a file in that same directory line by line starting at line number 14.
This is what I have so far but doesn't work.

cp workDir | grep -r --include *.text | sed -i '14i' home.text

Any assistance is appreciated. Note: I am on Unix.

Comment: can you explain it clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a directory called workDir and it has text files. I want to take the names of those text files and place it on line 14 in the file called home.text which is also in the directory workDir.

Comment: @NickJ Why on line 14?

Comment: There is content before line 14 in which I don't want to overwrite.

Comment: Is there content after 14th line?  In other words are you appending the data to existing file or inserting at a specific location?

Comment: Trying to insert in specific location between lines 14 and 17 on my file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cp workDir` doesn't work, because `cp` is for copying like `cp source destination`. Further explanations about `cp` can be read with `man cp`.

To achieve your goal go to your directory with `cd ~/path/to/workDir`. There you can use the `ls` command and redirect the output appending to your existing file with `>>` for all `.text` file extensions.

For example like this:

```
ls *.text >> home.text
```

This will append only the filenames line by line to your `home.text` without a preceding `./` like in the answer bevor with the `find` command.

Let me know If you like another format for your file names you want to append.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and your command did exactly what was looking for.

Comment: You are welcome. Please fell free to upvote my answer if this was an useful one with the arrow up left to the answer. By this other user which have the same issue like you will be pointed more directly to this quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the above task by following shell command:

```
find workDir -name "*.text" >> home.text
```

This will solve what you have commented.